# MS access table to return rows based on matching value of multiple columns

Tags: database, ms-access

I have a class_session table and a teacher profile form. So basically each class_session will be taught by more than 1 teacher at the same time, the structure of the table is like this:

Class_id|Teacher_1|Teacher_2

What I want to do is create a form in the teacher profile to show all the record of the teacher no matter he/she in the Teacher_1 or Teacher_2. So basically I want to see all the classes the teacher was involved.

Comment: Start by _normalising_ your tables, or you will continue to bump into issues.

Comment: Have you tried OR operator? Only 2 teachers possible?

Comment: Where should I put the OR operator? Right now this teaching history is a sub-form inside a tab control of the teacher profile.

Answer (score 0):

You should not design your tables the way you did. If you later on decided that a session can be taught by 5 teachers, you will need to add 4 more columns for the teachers, and this is not practical and not a good design.

You should have a table for the sessions and a table for the teachers:

- **class_session**: session_id|session_name|etc...
- **class_teachers**: teacher_id|teacher_name|etc...

Also, you should have a table for which user teaches which session:

- **sessions_teachers**: session_teacher_id|session_id|teacher_id

This way, you can add as many teachers to as many sessions as you need.

Now, in the teacher's form, you need to add a subform bound to a query. That query should fetch the data from the sessions_teachers table inner join the session and teacher tables and should filter out the records for the teacher in question.

Comment: You are very correct, however, in my situation a teacher can teach multiple session as long as they are certified for that course. The example I used is just to illustrate my design, according to the client, each session will have no more than 5 teacher. I know it is not the best practice to have a table structure like this, do you have any suggestions?